# Filter and merge two 2d arrays based on a shared column value

Tags: php, arrays, csv, filter, merge

I am trying to make a little batch upload tool to upload tracking numbers.

I have a csv with 2 columns: postal_code, tracking_number

and I have my sql that selects order_id, postal_code:

```
//import shipping csv with postal codes and tracking numbers and add to array
$csv_array = Array();
$file = fopen($_FILES['canada_post_csv']['tmp_name'], 'r');

if($file){
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        //$line is an array of the csv elements
        array_push($csv_array,$line);
    }
    fclose($file);
}

print_r($csv_array);

//select postal codes from orders that are of the status processing
$orders_query_raw = "select o.orders_id, o.delivery_postcode from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o where  o.orders_status = 2 and o.delivery_country = 'Canada'  order by orders_id DESC";

$orders_query = tep_db_query($orders_query_raw);
//$orders = tep_db_fetch_array($orders_query);
while ($orders = tep_db_fetch_array($orders_query)) {
    
    print_r( $orders );
}
//find matches between the imported csv array and the array of order postal codes
```

So I have the 2 arrays printing out:

From csv upload:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => delivery_postcode
        [1] => tracking
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => A0N 2H0
        [1] => 3197653232325
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => A3N 3A6
        [1] => 31976532323252
        )
)
```

From sql selection:

```
Array ( [orders_id] => 32061 [delivery_postcode] => V0R 2M0 ) Array ( [orders_id] => 32011 [delivery_postcode] => L8B1H5 ) Array ( [orders_id] => 31846 [delivery_postcode] => K0E1K0 ) Array ( [orders_id] => 31822 [delivery_postcode] => A0N 2H0 ) Array ( [orders_id] => 31503 [delivery_postcode] => V0J 1Z2 )
```

What I want to do is compare the postal codes from the csv with the postal codes from the sql selection. And then if a match is found select both the order_id and the tracking_number and push those to a new array together.

I am not sure about a few things:

1. my csv file open seems to be a different amount of dimensions to the array of my selection so I am not sure if that will matter but I think it will
2. I am not sure what to do to compare the postal codes. I think I will ned to use a foreach loop to check for matches but I am little shaky on this because they are different dimensions.
3. My postal codes have different formatting, some with spaces and some without so I think I will have to address that by converting the formatting to be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this result by using [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the `delivery_postcode` for each order in `$csv_array`, and if found, merging the entry from `$csv_array` with the entry from `$orders` to make the output tracking array. Note I have re-indexed `$csv_array` with the keys from the first line of the CSV file, and I am removing all spaces from the postcode values (so that e.g. `A0N2H0` will match `A0N 2H0`)  to make this possible.

```
$csv_keys = array_shift($csv_array);
$csv_array = array_map(function ($a) use ($csv_keys) { 
    return array_combine($csv_keys, array(str_replace(' ', '', $a[0]), $a[1]));
}, $csv_array);

$tracked = array();
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if (($key = array_search(str_replace(' ', '', $order['delivery_postcode']), array_column($csv_array, 'delivery_postcode'))) !== false) {
        $tracked[] = array_merge($order, $csv_array[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($tracked);
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orders_id] => 31822
            [delivery_postcode] => A0N2H0
            [tracking] => 3197653232325
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GD3KZ)

Comment: Thanks this seems to work and for the most part I understand it but I am pretty fuzzy on how the array_map function you wrote works to fix the spacing on the postal codes? I'm not sure if you'll care to explain it but a few things that are not quite clear to me -  why is the function just the  $a variable, and what does the "use" operator do (kind of understand but can't seem to find php documentation on use).

Comment: The `$a` variable represents the current value from `$csv_array` as `array_map` iterates over the values in it. so for the first entry, `$a = ['A0N 2H0', '3197653232325']` and the `str_replace` operates on `$a[0]` which is `A0N 2H0`. The `use` part of the declaration effectively acts as another parameter to the function, so that it can "see" `$csv_keys` inside it.

Comment: The section of the manual you're looking for is [Anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to search like this:

```
function search($id, $arr) 
{
   foreach ($arr as $key => $val) 
   {
       if ($val[0]==$id) 
       {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
$finallist=array();
```

And in the while loop:

```
while ($orders = tep_db_fetch_array($orders_query)) 
{
     $delivery_postcode=$orders['delivery_postcode'];
     if(search($delivery_postcode,$csv_array)==true)
     {
       $result=array("order_id"=>$orders['orders_id'],
       "delivery_postcode"=>$delivery_postcode);
        array_push($finallist,$result);
     }
}
print_r($finallist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Value searching between arrays is not going to be an efficient approach.  For better performance, use key searching.

First, set up your csv data to act as a lookup array by declaring unique first level keys as you parse each line of the file.  You might as well form associative elements in your lookup array to make merging simpler.

Then loop through your database result set and if a delivery_postcode value is found in the lookup array, then merge the associative arrays and push the new row into the result array.

Code:

```
$csv_array = [];
$file = fopen($_FILES['canada_post_csv']['tmp_name'], 'r');
if ($file) {
    $headers = fgetcsv($file);
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
        $line[0] = str_replace(' ', '', $line[0];
        $csv_array[$line[0]] = array_combine($headers, $line);
    }
    fclose($file);
}

$result = [];
if ($csv_array) {
    $sql = "SELECT orders_id, delivery_postcode
            FROM " . TABLE_ORDERS . "
            WHERE orders_status = 2
              AND delivery_country = 'Canada'
            ORDER BY orders_id DESC";
    $orders_query = tep_db_query($sql);
    while ($order = tep_db_fetch_array($orders_query)) {
        if (isset($csv_array[$order['delivery_postcode'])) {
            $result[] = $order + $csv_array[$order['delivery_postcode']];
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```